# Android Studio shows there has 1 usage but No usages found in All places

Tags: java, android, android-studio

1. How did I fine the problem?
   the Fragment's `onDestroy()` was triggered multiple times, accumulated and caused crash.
   [onDestroy() triggered multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVp6M.jpg)
2. What is the function
   ViewPager + Fragment
3. More detail

   a) It shows there has 2 usage but I just reference once.
   [2 usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Jpr.png)

   b) Then I remove the only reference.
   [1 usage but No usages found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uGO4.jpg)
4. I tried clean & rebuild project, make cache invalid, It has no effect.
5. I tried to remane the Fragment and all of problem disappeared(include `onDestroy()` was triggered multiple times), meanwhile the function can be used normally as before.
   [rename and the problem disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTY3Z.png)
6. If I still want to use the old name, I have to remove all of Fragment that FragmentManager holds.